# How to get value from field added in user settings

Tags: 7, entities, users

I am writing a module that performs a redirect based on what value was in a custom field called "field_account_type" that was added in user settings. How do I store this value in a variable within hook_user_login()?

Comment: Which hook are you using? Which user object do you need to access? Without those details, the answer can just be as vague as "load the user object, and load the field value using the appropriate field API function."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access `global $user` custom field values in the hook that suits you like this :

```
function your_hook() {
  global $user;
  $current_user = user_load($user->uid);
  $vars['account_type'] = $current_user->field_account_type[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```